# conditional inference trees in python

Tags: python, machine-learning

Is there a Python package that has a good implementation of conditional inference trees? I've looked through scikit-learn and done some googling but have come up with nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the details I came up with...

There doesn't seem to be an implementation in Python as yet. Though there was [a brief discussion](https://sourceforge.net/p/scikit-learn/mailman/message/31141698/) about some people desiring to implement it in sklearn a few years ago. However, based on [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12140/conditional-inference-trees-vs-traditional-decision-trees), it might be possible to modify the criterion parameter of the sklearn [decision tree implementation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html) to achieve the desired effect.

Alternatively, if you know R, the original implementation also exists [there](http://partykit.r-forge.r-project.org/partykit/).